# crontab with invalid values

Tags: bash, cron

In my bash script there is a line says as below

```
echo "2 30 * * * * /usr/bin/test.sh" >> /var/cron/crontabs/root
```

This apparently add a job to crontab, but since the second value should be in between 0-23. What would happen in this case?

Comment: What happens when you try it yourself?

Comment: `2 30 * * * *` is one field too much.

Comment: This is not the way to write a cronjob. Instead, use `crontab -e`. When you write this command (or any wrong one) you will get an error message like `"/tmp/crontab.R4mE4g":2: bad command`, `errors in crontab file, can't install.`

Answer (score 1):

There are no guarantees, because this is illegal.  This wording from the [`crontab(5)`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) man page suggests it will just be ignored:

> Note that this means that non-existent times, such as "missing hours" during daylight savings conversion, will never match, causing jobs scheduled during the "missing times" not to be run. Similarly, times that occur more than once (again, during daylight savings conversion) will cause matching jobs to be run twice.

However, the examples it gives are more reasonable scenarios (e.g. you specified to run a command at 2:30 AM local time on DST day in the spring, when there is no 2:30 AM).  The man page also says that the hour must be 0-23, and you've broken that rule.  It's possible `cron(8)` will complain in the syslog, or crash, or do any number of other things.  It's also possible it will be ignored, and it's likely this behavior will vary by Unix flavor.

In short, you're in uncharted territory.  Realistically, it probably won't crash outright, because daemons are not supposed to crash.  But other than that, you have few guarantees.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing at all. `cron` would refuse to run the line, (not because of the 0-23 issue), but because it is an invalid time specification attempting to contain **6** parameters while a correct `cron` entry has **5**.

```
crontab entry format:

  * * * * * command_to_execute
  | | | | |
  | | | | +- day of week  (0-6) (Sunday = 0)
  | | | +--- month        (1-12)
  | | +----- day of month (1-31)
  | +------- hour         (0-23)
  +--------- minute       (0-59)
```

Regardless of the values, the following will not work:

```
"2 30 * * * * /usr/bin/test.sh"
```

Comment: I think it won't run because 30 is not a valid hour. I don't think cron will recognize that there are too many time fields. I think it will attempt to execute `*` as a command -- after expanding it to a list of the files in your home directory. If the first file name happens to match a valid command name, it should execute that. (Now I'll have to try it to see if it actually works.) ... Nope, I get "errors in crontab file, can't install". Oh, well.

Comment: But on Solaris 9 (which uses a non-Vixie crontab implementation), it actually works. And `$PATH` is set to `/usr/bin:` (with an implicit trailing `.`), so by executing the command `*` it actually executes the first listed file in my home directory, with the names of all the other files as arguments. Aren't wildcards fun!